# How to change shape, position to markers [tradingview charting library]

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, tradingview-api

I created this marker, now I want to change it's shape and position. Please help me to find its solution.

```
getMarks: (symbolInfo,startDate,endDate,onDataCallback,resolution) => {
    var arr = [
        {
            id: 1,
            time:  1683185400000 / 1000,
            color: 'yellow',
            text: ['hello'],
            label: 'how',
            labelFontColor: 'black',
            minSize: 20,
            // shape: 'rectangle',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            time:  1681975800000 / 1000,
            color: 'red',
            text: '400',
            label: 'c',
            labelFontColor: 'green',
            minSize: 20,
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            time:  1681111800000 / 1000,
            color: 'yellow',
            text: '500',
            label: 'd',
            labelFontColor: 'white',
            minSize: 20,
        },
    ]
   
    onDataCallback(arr);


},
```

now  markers looks like this

[image]

But I want to show markers in this format

[image]